# How to revert an automatic subproject commit in git

Tags: git, git-revert, subproject

I have couple of submodules in my project and I inadvertently made some changes to the modules.
Though I did not explicitly check in the changes, I see the subproject commits when I diff the repository.[image]
(Using stash)

When I do a `git status` on my local repo. it showed a `(modified content)` against the subproject. So I moved to the subdirectory of the subproject and discarded the changes. When I do a git status now, the (modified content) does not show. However, since there are no commits, I cannot check in or revert the inadvertent commit shown in pic. `git revert <green commit hash in pic>` errors out as there is no such commit in my local repo.

Please help me understand how I can revert the commit on my subproject. These commits do not show even when I go into the subdirectory of the subproject.

Comment: Try checking the [reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). You can grep the output with a hash or a commit message to help you find the commit that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best way, but I found out how to do it.

1. I discard all my changes on my subproject by `git checkout -- <file>`
2. When I do a git branch on the subproject, it shows it's detached
   from HEAD. I do a `git pull origin master`.
3. Now , when I go to the root project and do a git status, it shows
   `(new commits)` besides the subproject. Add the subproject 
   using `git add <subproject-name>`  and `git commit`
4. `git push` the changes to the remote repository.